# Overwrite variable in function from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can overwrite variable in function from another file.

---

### 2. Example

#### 2.1. Configuration

I use [**logbook**](http://logbook.pocoo.org/) and [**pyfancy**](https://github.com/ilovecode1/Pyfancy-2) modules.

I have 2 files — `config.py` and `first.py`:

`config.py`:

```python
import logbook
import sys

from pyfancy.pyfancy import pyfancy

log = logbook.Logger("config")


logbook.StreamHandler(sys.stdout,
                      level=logbook.DEBUG).push_application()


def green_foreground(coloredtext):
    log.debug(pyfancy().green().bold(coloredtext))
```

`first.py`:

```python
import logbook

from config import green_foreground

log = logbook.Logger("first")

green_foreground("Sasha Champion!")
```

---

### 3. Steps to reproduce

I run in console:

```
python first.py
```

---

### 4. Expected behavior

I want, that `log` variable:

- `log = logbook.Logger("first")` — in `first.py`,
- `log = logbook.Logger("second")` — in `second.py` and so on.

```shell
D:\PyfancyRefactoring>python first.py
[2018-01-25 16:54:25.469005] DEBUG: first: Sasha Champion!
```

---

### 5. Actual behavior

Value of `log` variable from `config.py` file.

```shell
D:\PyfancyRefactoring>python first.py
[2018-01-25 16:54:25.469005] DEBUG: config: Sasha Champion!
```

---

### 6. Not helped

For example, I add to `config.py`:

```python
if __name__ == 'config':
    log = logbook.Logger("config")
else:
    log = logbook.Logger("first")
```

I get actual behavior, not expected behavior.

---

### 7. Do not offer

1. I know that I can define `green_foreground` function in each file, but it will be a lot of duplicate code and I think, that it a not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The config file creates a logger, named `config`, and the function green_foreground logs to that logger. It is hard coded that way - at no point do you tell the green_foreground function to log anywhere else, it has no idea about the log created in first.py.

When you run first.py, python creates two different `log` instances. You can modify the green_foreground function to accept a `log` instance as an argument and default to the one creatd in `config`, or:

change `config.py` to log this instead:

```
log = logbook.Logger(__name__)
```

Comment: Danielle M.: I add in `config.py` `log = logbook.Logger(__name__)` instead of `log = logbook.Logger("config")` → I run in console `python first.py` → I still get actual behavior, not expected behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand why the program behaves the way it does? You need to tell the green_foreground function to use the logger defined in first.py. How might you do that?

Comment: DanielleM.: `You need to tell the green_foreground function to use the logger defined in first.py. How might you do that? ` — this is the question, that I asked :-) . Thanks.